# Wordpress wp_insert_post function not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in my root wordpress folder in a file called wp_insert_post.php
However when I run this url from the browser I just get a blank page. None of the echo statements appear. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
require_once('wp-config.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
echo "done1";

$post = array(
  'ID' => [] 
  'menu_order' => ['0'] 
  'page_template' => [] 
  'comment_status' => ['closed'] 
  'ping_status' => ['open']
  'pinged' => [] //?
  'post_author' => ['1'] 
  'post_category' => []
  'post_content' => ['testautopage123']
  'post_date' => ['2013-05-18 18:39:33'] 
  'post_date_gmt' => ['2013-05-18 18:39:33']
  'post_excerpt' => []
  'post_name' => ['test-auto-page']
  'post_parent' => [] 
  'post_password' => []
  'post_status' => ['publish']
  'post_title' => ['Test Page']
  'post_type' => ['page']
  'tags_input' => []
  'to_ping' => []); 
echo "done2";
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post($post);
echo "done3";
?>
```

Comment: Is there something in your error_log?

Comment: the array syntax is wrong. array should be $post = array('menu_order' => 0,  'page_template' => null ....

Comment: yea that was the problem, thanks!

Comment: `post_title` and `post_content` are both required https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format is not good. Try it like this ( taken from the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) )

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

So, remove the `[` and `]` and add commas `,` after each parameter in the array.