# WP_INSERT_POST from Form Data, Using WPDB->GetResults

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, forms, custom-post-type

I have a series of custom tables which hold distillery operations data on the same MySQL DB as my Wordpress. I would like to use WPDB->GetResults and then WP_INSERT_POST to take form data and create a custom post type from certain distillery table entries. I have an HTML form trying to send a request to a PHP file (code below). I notice that I cannot even see the PHP when opening the webpage. There must be something wrong with this. When debugging the form submission, I am good up until my $.ajax({ call, but I think the .php file is getting me down.

-Newbie doing his best

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Goofball</p>
<?php
require('header.php');
require('mydomain/test/wp-includes/wp-db.php')

if(isset($_POST['mashId'])){
    $mashId = $_REQUEST['mashId']; 
    new_mash_post($mashId);
 }

function new_mash_post($mashId) {
    // Initialize the page ID to -1. This indicates no action has been taken.
    $post_id = -1;

    $mashes = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT * 
    FROM mash a
    INNER JOIN mashbill b ON a.mashId = b.mashId
    INNER JOIN mash_ferm_junc c ON a.mashId = c.mashId
    WHERE a.mashId = $mashId
    "
    );

    $oldmashid = 0; 
    foreach($mashes as $mash){

        if($oldmashid != 0){
            $oldmashid = $mash->mashId;
            $slug = $mash->mashId;
            $title = $mash->mashId;
            $author_id = 1;

            // If the page doesn't already exist, then create it
            if( null == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {

                // Set the post ID so that we know the post was created successfully
                $post_id = wp_insert_post(
                array(
                'comment_status'    =>  'closed',   
                'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
                'post_name'     =>  $slug,
                'post_title'        =>  $title,
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'post_type'     =>  'your_bottle'
                )
                );

                $json_result = array( 'success' => true, 'post_id' => $post_id);
                                echo json_encode( $json_result );

            // Otherwise, we'll stop
            } else {

                // Arbitrarily use -2 to indicate that the page with the title already exists
                    $post_id = -2;
                    echo json_encode("failed");

            } // end if


        }   //end if mashId is new
    } //end for loop over selection results


} // end programmatically_create_post
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to all of those who've asked similar questions before. I'm only asking because I wasn't able to really fix my issues on [WordPress.org][1], [another thread][3], [this page][4].

[1]:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post/
[3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634528/wordpress-wp-insert-post-function-not-working/
[4]: https://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/